# Strange Webconfig and Mysql Issue

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, web-config, forms-authentication

I have two sections in my webconfig that I think are an issue.  The first one I put an arrow pointing
to the line that the web configuration tool says it is having problems with.  I think its strange that it is 
pointing to the last line and not at the top of this entry.  The error i have when I go to the security tab
is :

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, 
or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. 
Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: 
    Unknown database 'Database' (D:\ASPX\testing\testing\web.config line 42)

```
<add applicationName="/" description="MySQL default application"
      connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False"
      autogenerateschema="True" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="False"
      passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySQLMembershipProvider"
===>>>>>  type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

The second issue is with the session state. All the Attributes after PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" are 
flagged "attribute is not allowed"

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
   <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True"/>
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```

P.S. I tried adding applicationName and Description using the MySQL Configurator, but it didn't update webconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this error.  First I reinstalled MySQL, my entire Schema's were still there.  That didn't fix the issue.  I then dropped all the tables in the schema, thinking that the auto generate would rebuild them.  That also didn't work.  I ended up dropping the schema and recreating it. This allowed everything to work correctly.  I don't know what was causing the issue but it had to be something at the schema level.

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown database 'Database'` suggests that the conn string named `LocalMySqlServer` has incorrect database name (or database name that doesn't exists on the server specified in that conn string, or that the specified user account doesn't have permissions to access it).

If you do have that database on the specified server, then it must be that permissions for that user need to be adjusted.